# Call .js file from another .js file

Tags: javascript

I have one javascript program in my module; say `test1.js`. It has `IF..ELSEIF` statements. My challenge is I want to call different `.js` programs based on conditions in `IF-ELSE` statements.

`TEST1.js` looks like -

```
-----
if(cond1) {
   //want to call test2.js here
}
else if(cond2) {
   //want to call test3.js here
}
```

How do I do this in javascript?

Comment: What do your other JS files look like? Have you tried using functions?

Comment: it has few array variables and few functions. I mean there is javascript code in every `.js` file. I have created different `.js` file based on conditions as code in those files is somewhat large. if i inserted it under `IF..ELSE` statement then it may get messup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if(cond1) 
    {
       //want to call test2.js here
            var js = document.createElement("script");
            js.type = "text/javascript";
            js.src = "test2.js";
            document.body.appendChild(js);
    }
    else if(cond2) 
    {
            //want to call test3.js here

            var js = document.createElement("script");
            js.type = "text/javascript";
            js.src = "test3.js";
            document.body.appendChild(js);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

test1.js

```
var arr={}; //array
```

test2.js

```
function alertOne() {
     if(cond1) {
   //from test1.js here
     alert(arr);
     }
     else if(cond2) {
     }
}
```

in HTML

```
<head>
    <script src="test1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="test2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<head>
```

Use this method.